# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I'm getting the following message while trying to compile a CUDA program:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart

Never got this kind of error before. Is it any problem with my PATH?

Here's the compile command:

> gfortran  -g -O2 -ffree-line-length-none -I../shared/ -o
>   ../../bin/xspecfem3D ../../obj/spec/program_specfem3D.o
>   ../../obj/spec/specfem3D_par.o ../../obj/spec/PML_init.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_boundary_kernel.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_kernels.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_acoustic.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_acoustic_pot.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_acoustic_PML.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_elastic.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_elastic_Dev.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_elastic_noDev.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_elastic_Dev_openmp.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_add_sources_acoustic.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_add_sources_elastic.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_coupling_acoustic_el.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_coupling_elastic_ac.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_stacey_acoustic.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_stacey_elastic.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_gradient.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_interpolated_dva.o
>   ../../obj/spec/initialize_simulation.o
>   ../../obj/spec/read_mesh_databases.o ../../obj/spec/setup_GLL_points.o
>   ../../obj/spec/write_movie_output.o
>   ../../obj/spec/create_color_image.o ../../obj/spec/write_seismograms.o
>   ../../obj/spec/write_output_ASCII.o
>   ../../obj/spec/detect_mesh_surfaces.o
>   ../../obj/spec/setup_movie_meshes.o
>   ../../obj/spec/read_topography_bathymetry.o
>   ../../obj/spec/setup_sources_receivers.o
>   ../../obj/spec/prepare_timerun.o ../../obj/spec/iterate_time.o
>   ../../obj/spec/finalize_simulation.o
>   ../../obj/spec/save_adjoint_kernels.o ../../obj/spec/specfem3D.o
>   ../../obj/spec/assemble_MPI_vector.o ../../obj/spec/make_gravity.o
>   ../../obj/spec/noise_tomography.o  ../../lib/libspecfem.a
>   ../../obj/spec/check_fields_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_add_sources_acoustic_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_add_sources_elastic_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_coupling_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_acoustic_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_forces_elastic_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_kernels_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_stacey_acoustic_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/compute_stacey_elastic_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/it_update_displacement_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/noise_tomography_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/prepare_mesh_constants_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/transfer_fields_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/write_seismograms_cuda.cuda.o
>   ../../obj/spec/save_and_compare_cpu_vs_gpu.cudacc.o 
>   ../../obj/spec/serial.o   -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Edit:

I've changed the linkage command to

> gfortran -g -O2 -ffree-line-length-none -I../shared/ -L$CUDA_HOME/lib [rest follows]

And all my PATHs seems to be OK, but I'm still having the same error.

Edit2:

The error was that the code I was trying to compile was in 64bit, so I needed to give the path a diferent set of .so's , which are located on

> /usr/local/cuda/lib64

Now the compilation ran fine ans without any problems.

Comment: Can you post the compile command or makefile you are using for this?

Comment: Sure, but it's really kinda big...

Comment: Do you have the CUDA `toolkit` installed ?

Comment: Of course, I've installed it alongside with the CUDA itself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not specifying the location of the CUDA libraries to the linker, that is why the linkage is failing. `nvcc` is "automagically" configured to find the CUDA runtime library components, but if you are linking with a host compiler directly, you will need to explicitly specify their location to the compiler. Try changing the linkage command to this:

```
gfortran -g -O2 -ffree-line-length-none -I../shared/ -L$CUDA_HOME/lib [rest follows]
```

where `CUDA_HOME` denotes the path where the CUDA toolkit is installed. Typically this is `/usr/local/cuda` on linux and OS X systems. You will then need to make sure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains an entry for `$CUDA_HOME/lib` so that the executable will dynamically load the required CUDA libraries at runtime.

**EDIT:**

Also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510176/result-of-make-command-is-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lcudart)

Comment: What did not work? How did it not work? Can you update your question?

Comment: I've updated the linkage command and LD_LIBRARY_PATH does have the entry for $CUDA_HOME/lib , yet the same error still happens.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this! Go to your makefile and change /usr/local/cuda/ to /usr/local/cuda-7.0 (if that's what you got)
It worked for me

Comment: Where is this makefile located? Could you be more specific?